# Lucene: get newest document for category

Tags: java, lucene

I'm pretty new to lucene index, so I apologize in advance if what I am trying to do is trivial.
I have an index where the documents contain (among other) two fields:

`documentoId` and `employeeId`.

Each employee can submit various documents. The structure is pretty much the same as in the [bookstore](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/facet/org/apache/lucene/facet/doc-files/userguide.html#facet_accumulation) example.
What I am trying to achieve, is to get  all the newest documents matching a query, meaning with the highest `documentoId` for each `employeeId`.

In SQL, this would be something like: 

`select max(documentoId ), employeeId
from documents
where content like 'mySearchValue' 
group by employeeId`

I don't know if I should use facet API, or if this can be done with queries, or with the searchAfter method...I'm pretty lost with the documentation.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lucene supports grouping search; what you need to do is to define your group and how does it have to be sorted. In the example below, I group by `documentoId` and sort in descending order.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException {
    StandardAnalyzer standardAnalyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_46);
    RAMDirectory ramDirectory = new RAMDirectory();

    IndexWriter indexWriter = new IndexWriter(ramDirectory, new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_46, standardAnalyzer));

    Document d0 = new Document();
    d0.add(new TextField("employeeId", "foo", Field.Store.YES));
    d0.add(new IntField("documentoId", 1, Field.Store.YES));
    indexWriter.addDocument(d0);

    Document d1 = new Document();
    d1.add(new TextField("employeeId", "bar", Field.Store.YES));
    d1.add(new IntField("documentoId", 20, Field.Store.YES));
    indexWriter.addDocument(d1);

    Document d2 = new Document();
    d2.add(new TextField("employeeId", "baz", Field.Store.YES));
    d2.add(new IntField("documentoId", 3, Field.Store.YES));
    indexWriter.addDocument(d2);

    indexWriter.commit();

    GroupingSearch groupingSearch = new GroupingSearch("documentoId");
    Sort groupSort = new Sort(new SortField("documentoId", SortField.Type.INT, true));  // in descending order
    groupingSearch.setGroupSort(groupSort);
    groupingSearch.setSortWithinGroup(groupSort);

    IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(ramDirectory);
    IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);

    TopGroups<?> groups = groupingSearch.search(searcher, new MatchAllDocsQuery(), 0, 10);

    Document highestScoredDocument = reader.document(groups.groups[0].scoreDocs[0].doc);
    System.out.println(
            "Descending order, first document is " +
                    "employeeId:" + highestScoredDocument.get("employeeId") + " " +
                    "documentoId:" + highestScoredDocument.get("documentoId")
    );
}
```

The above code detects that the `d1` (middle document) scores at the top and prints the following:

> Descending order, first document is employeeId:bar documentoId:20

Above code does not address `content like 'mySearchValue'` part, you would have to replace `MatchAllDocsQuery` with a relevant query to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Custom sorting of the hits will do the trick. Google the `search.sort` parameter in Lucene.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mark! I tried to use Sort but the closest I came was to order by employeeId asc, documentoId desc , and then manually select only one result for each employee. I'm not sure this is the right way to do it. Is this what you were thinking of? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For those in the same situation, I solved my problem using mindas comment and modifying it to use my group field:

```
GroupingSearch groupingSearch = new GroupingSearch("employeeId");
Sort groupSort = new Sort(new SortField("documentoId", SortField.Type.INT, true));  // in descending order
groupingSearch.setGroupSort(groupSort);
groupingSearch.setSortWithinGroup(groupSort);


int offset = 0;
int limitGroup = 50;
TopGroups<?> groups = groupingSearch.search(is,query, offset, limitGroup);

List<Document> result = new ArrayList();
for (int i=0; i<groups.groups.length; i++) {
    ScoreDoc sdoc = groups.groups[i].scoreDocs[0]; // first result of each group
    Document d = is.doc(sdoc.doc);
    result.add(d);
 }
```